# Analysis of Cost Efficiency - Economics of?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I'm in search for a title that says: You can expect to read about how economic efficient different things are when compared against each other.

As I need a noun, grabbing the word *economical* and turning it into *economicality of* doesn't really cut it, because I don't even think that is a proper English word.

Is *economics of* the correct term? Somehow that gives a more internal feeling, as in economics of scale, and not as in

> these things affect overall cost in such and such a way

Is there a better term than the non-existent word *economicality*?

Answer (score 3):

Why not **[cost-effectiveness](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cost-effectiveness)**

> (business) the ability to provide adequate financial return in relation to outlay
>
> *The board will look at the drug's cost-effectiveness.*
>
> *A Home Office report has raised doubts about the cost-effectiveness of the proposals.*